# Google Maps OpenGL 3D makes my system unstable (hangup)

Tags: 12.04, opengl, google-maps

Running Ubuntu 12.04LTS.  I tried to load Google Maps with the OpenGL 3D new functionality. My system does weird things graphically and still reports system errors after reboot.  What shall I do?

BTW, I cannot access maps any more, if I do the system crashes again.

Comment: 12.04 LTS, Sandy Bridge card. I was using Chrome.
What else is required?

Comment: MapsGL runs on WebGL, make sure Chrome has WebGL enabled by entering the url `chrome://flags` in chrome.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I am on 12.04 as well. Visiting the URL below will restore your access to Google Maps.

http://maps.google.com/?vector=0

See [here](http://support.google.com/maps/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1630790) for more details: